# Closing winform form and stopping it´s execution

Tags: c#, winforms

<strike>All my forms inherits from a base form("Base").</strike>

There, when it inicializes, I call a method called "Acceso" (access) that returns true or false based on the current user privilegies to access or not.

```
public Base()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Acceso();
    }

public void Acceso()
    {
        Type tipo = this.GetType();
        if (Metodos.Login.Acceso(tipo) == false)
        {
            WMessageBox.Show("Su usuario no posee los privilegios necesarios para acceder a esta ventana.", "Error", 2, false);
            this.Close();
            this.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

The issue is that if it returns false, the forms closes perfectly, but I get an exception after it. Apparently, the form continues running. I tried to solve this by disposing it, but I just got the same problem.

How can I terminate the form? Is there any way to stop and destroy the instance?

EDIT: Actually this is happening because it wants to show the deleted form.

```
form.Show();
```

I wrote this question because I thought it was happening the same thing as in another form.

In that form, I have a panel where I load my UserControls.
When I create an instance of the UserControl and add it to the panel, I assign the form to a Form type variable in the UserControl. That is because if the users gets an exception in that UserControl, I do a form.Close() to close the entire Form.

This is how I load the UserControl(its in a button):

```
 private void btn_Administracion_grupos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dispose_User_Control();
        ABM.frm_Administracion_Grupos administracion_grupos = new ABM.frm_Administracion_Grupos();
        administracion_grupos.form = this;
        pnl_UserControl.Controls.Add(administracion_grupos);
    }
```

administracion_grupos is the form.

In Dispose_User_Control(), I remove the UserControl from the panel and dispose it:

```
public void Dispose_User_Control()
    {
        if (pnl_UserControl.Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                UserControl frm = (UserControl)pnl_UserControl.Controls[0];
                frm.Dispose();
            }
            catch
            {

            }

            pnl_UserControl.Controls.Clear();
        }
    }
```

Then, in the FormClosing() event, I dispose the UserControl in the panel and the form.

```
private void frm_Configuracion_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Dispose_User_Control();
        this.Dispose();
    }
```

When I get an excepction in my UserControl this is what I do:

```
try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
                WMessageBox.Show("Grupo guardado con éxito.", "Confirmación", 3, false);
            }
            catch(Exception excep)
            {
                Control.Mensajes_error.Error_transaccion(excep);
                form.Close();
            }
```

I cath it, and I close the form (The form with the panel).

But after the closing(the form is not showed anymore), I get an exception in lines of code inside the UserControl. Thats why I wanted a way to terminate the entire form.

The exception I´m getting is in a line of code where I´m using a datagridview. It justs says null reference. Then I as said, the main form is closed, the UserControls is disposed, but it just continues executing code!

Comment: "I get an exception after it" -- what exception?

Comment: I just edited what happened. I thought I was getting the same exception as I had in another form.

Comment: @Andres, so what exactly is happening? And how about you put the exact exception text into the question for us.

Comment: @Andres: Also, why don't you just do the check before even loading the form?

Comment: Thank you Bryan, that issue has been solved, as I said, the app wanted to show a deleted instance. That was the error. I just didnt pay attention to it because I was getting a similar issue in a parent form with usercontrols in it. Check what I wrote now..

Comment: Nice you solved it, even nicer to let us know. :-) Still voting to close though, if you don't mind.

Comment: Well @CodeCaster the solved part is striked. I just didnt solve the part below the EDIT i wrote.

Comment: You wrote a lot about the code, perhaps it's useful to show it?

Comment: @CodeCaster code is added now :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Environment.Exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit.aspx) methode for that